# Homework: need to check the time performance of the loop, computer heats

Tags: python, performance, time, python-3.x

I typed this code in python and my computer really heats and doesn't print anything! however when I assigned `num = 2**10` it did. How can I calculate approx. how long will it take for an average computer to run this code?
the code is:

```
num = 2**100
cnt = 0
import time
t0 = time.clock()
for i in range(num):
    cnt = cnt+1
print(cnt)
t1 = time.clock()
print("running time: ", t1-t0, " sec")
```

Comment: `10**9` is going to take a lot of time.

Comment: but why? if I type snum = str(num) 
for digit in snum: 
 if digit == "0": 
 cnt = cnt+1 , it calculates it fast

Comment: you will get memory errors using range ... try using xrange instead

Comment: @JoranBeasley python3.x :)

Comment: How is that in any way the same thing? That simply prints the number of zeroes in 2**30. That's quite different from counting up from 0 to 2**30.

Comment: Why not try assigning `2<<30` (shift left) instead of `2**30`?

Comment: oh is range an iterator in py3 ... oops :P @ sonic ... I dont think the 2**3 calculation is what takes so long ... its the loop

Comment: @CnR As Daniel already said, they're not the same thing. Using `str(num)` you're iterating over just 10 characters and in range(2**30) you're iterating over around 10**9 items.

Comment: If you run this in 2.7.x it still works (although it uses a ton of memory). I'm wondering if OP is actually not using Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ipython notebook for this.
It has a magic function called %%timeit, where you can do this sort of things.

Maybe `2**30` it's too much. The O for this kind of thing is `O(2**n)`. It means that `2**30` would take approximately 2*20 more time than `2**10`. And that's a lot of time.

Look the times using IPython:

[image]

Do the math, and double the time 20 more times, to see how much it would take using 2**30.

Comment: I think you mean O(2^n) and not O(2*n)

Comment: Can you explain me how to calculate it? I didn't undersand. in fact, I have to calculate how long it will take to run the program for 2**100

Comment: You are iterating through a list. That time is linear. Each time you add 1 to the power of two (from 2^20 to 2^21), you multiply the length by two, thus doubling the time needed in the interaction, got it?

So, if you want to estimate time to 2**100, take the time it took to do 2**20, and double it 80 times. Thats what O(n**2) means. Note that is a rough estimate. There are many factors that comes in factor, like language optimizations, size of the numbers analyzed, etc.

Comment: And other thing. Take the print statement out of your time counting. It will take much more time to print than to calculate it. Thus, keeping the printing statement where it is now will bias your metric.

ps. please accept my answer, if it you think it answered your question.

Comment: I think I understood. after I delete the print command (I don't need it , it was just so I can see where I am standing here): calculate how long it took for the input 2**20, and then multiply the time I got by 2**80? (I guess it's pretty basic but.. in addition what is O(n**2) and how do you know it)

Comment: for 2**20 it took 0.16170256312187936  sec. now should I multiply it by 2**80? I get a huge number, and then divided it by 3600 to get the number of hours it would take, and its a huge number doesnt make sense to me , Im doing something wrong..

Comment: Thats why the other answers told your computer wouldnt ever finish the computation. Your answer is right. Look at the "O" here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: I read but Im not sure how did toy get to O(n^2) and not O(n)?

Answer (score 1):

That's because your computer doesn't ever finish the computation with 2**30.

Comment: on my medium fast machine 2**30 takes 78 seconds

Comment: 11 seconds on my old machine with PyPy 2.1 and 262 seconds with CPython 3.3.2.

Comment: 264 seconds with CPython on mine

Answer (score 0):

If your indents are accurate to what you're running, your code may not be making it to the print function, which would make it look like the script is not doing anything.

```
for i in range(num):
    cnt = cnt+1
print(cnt)
```

is not the same as:

```
for i in range(num):
    cnt = cnt+1
    print(cnt)
```

If you want to check the progress of your script, you can use occasional print statements, by using mod. You can play around with the delay amount, depending on your computer's speed, but I would only print progress updates every 2-5 seconds.

```
delay = 5000
for i in range(num):
    cnt = cnt+1
    if i % delay == 0:
        print("Current interation: {}".format(cnt))   # Will only print when i is divisible by the delay amount
```